# How do I pass a 2D string array to a click event?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to pass a 2d string array as a parameter to a click event (searchButton_Click)  which is generated within a click event so I can perform a search function. However, I get the error `No overload for 'searchButton_Click' matches delegate 'RoutedEventHandler'.`

I have tried several solutions as seen on stackoverflow and other sources but none has worked.
I'm new to C# programming, any help will be appreciated.

```
private string[,] LongRunningTask()
        {
            workSheetName = getWorkSheetName();
            var sourceFile = OpenExcelFile(filePath);
            var sourceWorkSheet = GetWorkSheet(sourceFile.Item1, sourceFile.Item2, workSheetName);  //instantiating the object.
            var doc_Max = GetDocRow_Col(sourceWorkSheet.Item1);
            var maxRow_Col = GetMaxRow_Col(sourceWorkSheet.Item1, doc_Max.Item1, doc_Max.Item2);
            int maxRowCount = maxRow_Col.Item1;
            int maxColCount = maxRow_Col.Item2;
            WriteLine("Last column with content is Row {0} ", maxRowCount);
            WriteLine("Last column with content is Column {0} ", maxColCount);
            var getItemsResult = getItems(sourceWorkSheet.Item1, maxRow_Col);

            string[,] itemsArr = getItemsResult;

            Bindng2DArrayToListview2(listview, itemsArr, maxColCount);
            //enableItems();
            GarbageCollector(sourceWorkSheet.Item1, sourceWorkSheet.Item2, sourceWorkSheet.Item3, sourceWorkSheet.Item4);


            //searchButton.Click += (sender2, e2) => { searchButton_Click(sender2, e2, itemsArr); };

            return itemsArr;
        }

        private async void StartTask()
        {
            this.progressLabel.Content = "Getting Sheets..";
            try
            {
                await Task.Run(() => LongRunningTask());
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }
            this.progressLabel.Content = "Done";
        }
```

Comment: Is this a WPF app?

Comment: You can always "flatten" the string array into just a string, with elements separated by comma or semi-colon or whatever you like, then in method searchButton_Click parse that string back to your 2d array (if I understand your question correctly).

Comment: A WPF button click handler has a specific signature (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) because it's defined by WPF itself - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.click?view=netframework-4.8 so you can't overload it. From your code it looks like you're binding itemsArr to a listview so why do you need to pass this to the click handler ?

Comment: @stuartd yes it is.

Comment: @auburg After itemsArr has been bound to the listview, i want the user to be able to filter out items from itemsArr and display them accordingly. Hope this makes sense. If possible what will be the best way to search through itemsArr?

Comment: @GeoffreyFernandez that way, I will not be able to display it similar to how I currently use the listview. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: So make whatever that's calling LongRunningTask save the return value and then you've got the array ? BTW you've not shown the code that's calling that LongRunningTask which would help.

Comment: Ahh okay, so if i can get StartTask() to return the 2D array, how will I be able to make use of it in a click event?since I will not be able to overload it?

Comment: You don't need to have `itemsArr` returned from `StartTask` (I think, it's not clear what causes `StartTask` to run). You just need to store the result of `LongRunningTask` in a class member, such as a field. Then you access that field inside the `searchButton_Click` event.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the result of `LongRunningTask` into a field on the class (which I assume is the `Window` itself), then just access that field from `searchButton_Click`.

For example...

```
public partial class TheWindow : Window
{
   private string[,] LongRunningTask()
   {
      // Your LongRunningTask implementation.
   }

   private async Task StartTask()
   {
      progressLabel.Content = "Getting Sheets...";
      try
      {
         _itemsArr = await Task.Run(() => LongRunningTask());
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
         MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
      }
      progressLabel.Content = "Done!";
   }

   private void searchButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
      if (_itemsArr == null)
      {
         // The field is null for some reason. You'll have to decide what to do in this case, but
         // naturally you can't use it if it's null.
         return;
      }
      // Do the search using the field _itemsArr.
   }

   private string[,] _itemsArr = null;
}
```